# GWT Detecting if browser scroll reached bottom

Tags: java, gwt

I want to detect if scroll reached end of the page and react on it

Code:

```
    Window.addWindowScrollHandler(new ScrollHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onWindowScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
              //code for Detecting if reached end     
        }
    });
```

Does not work for me. It Never catches that event.

Comment: Are you using ScrollPanel as a main component ?

Comment: I want get event from browser scrollbar, not the one associated with scrollPanel.